# PHP & JQuery : Cookies in Real-Time

Tags: php, jquery, cookies

I am not too sure if this is possible which is why I am asking before I attempt it. The idea is to build a login file in `PHP` which when the credentials are correct, the `$_COOKIE['fid']` is changed to a `login key`.

This file is going to be used using `JQuery` with a function `$.post`.

Is it possible to do a real-time cookie refresh in `JQuery` or `PHP` because the idea is that there is no `response` if the login is `TRUE`, the `PHP` code should pick-up that the cookie is now `SET`

PHP example:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['fid'])):
   // do something
endif;
```

Or is this not possible because as soon as the page finishes loading, the if statements have already been returned `true` or `false` ?

I'd just love to be able to make some kind of background refresh which then the `PHP` code picks up and then does something so its all real-time.

Edit: I found this code to update it, but how would the `PHP` code know its been updated?

```
$('#login').click(function(){
     _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'viewerChose', $.cookie('whichSide')+'side']);
});
```

Comment: PHP doesn't knows if it's update since you don't reload the page or make a request by ajax. In resume you must to contact the server to update cookies's values in server, not in client

Comment: See, if I sent an AJAX request, developer tools can be used to switch the else & if round to the login is true without input :/ That's why the PHP idea of an event which corresponds to the update would of just been perfect. @MarcosPérezGude

Comment: There is no "events" in PHP (at least something like javascript events), so you need to make an ajax dummy request to load the new values in cookies in the server. Sorry if this doesn't fit with your requirements.

Comment: So the idea of what I want doesn't actually exist? @MarcosPérezGude

Comment: You can't manage cookies in real-time by the server, since the server needs to contact mannually to achieve this. You can make an ajax request or reload the page (the reload solution is answered by yourself :)). Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[@MarcosPérezGude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5035890/marcos-p%C3%A9rez-gude)** has explained in the `Comments` section that this isn't actually possible.

The only way to work with the update would to send it via `AJAX` methods and work with a response, however, this means the response has to be handled in `JavaScript` and not `PHP`.

Maybe one day they will make this possible haha.

**Example of doing it the way that is possible -**

JQuery:

```
$("#login-btn").click(function(){
    $("#login-load-icon").css("display") = "block";
    $.post( "example.php", { user: "example", pass: "example").done(function(data){
        if(data == 1){
            location.reload();
        } else {
            $("#login-error").css("display") = "block";
            $("#login-load-icon").css("display") = "none";
        }
    });
});
```

example.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])):
    if(strtoupper($_POST['user']) == strtoupper("This would a Database Query")):
        if($_POST['pass'] == "This would you matching the hashed pass with the hash in the DB"):
            setcookie("fid", "LOGIN KEY HERE", time()+3600, "/");
        endif;
    endif;
endif;
// etc...
```

Then on the page you're in:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['fid')):
        if($_COOKIE['fid'] == $Database['login_key']):
            // get all the user details and they're logged in
        else:
            // they tried to trick your system
    else:
        // load the login-btn
    endif;
```